# how to deploy kubernetes application in EKS through Jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I'm trying to deploy Kubernetes application in AWS EKS through Jenkins.

I visited few of blogs, they mentioned Jenkins X. But JenkinsX need to be configured separately. But as per instruction, we need to use our existing Jenkins for K8S app deployment.

Note : AWS EKS and Jenkins are Separate machine(We using our existing Jenkins). I may need to create New EKS environment based on requirement.

Please suggest if any **AWS EKS plugin for Jenkins** which can be used for deployment.

***Else***

Is there any way to create **custom Bash script(automation script) for deploying K8S application** in AWS EKS?

My Research here is : Actually AWS is providing api/sdk support for only Creating/Managing Clusters but not deploying the application in k8s environment(using `kubectl`).

Probably creating cluster we can do it through SDK. but How to deploy k8s application on remotely(because Jenkins is running in another machine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I'm done this exercise by creating **Bash automation script**,  following these steps:

1. Created Docker image with application binary.
2. Created EKS Cluster using `eksctl create cluster <PARAM>`, which creates EKS Control Plane and Worker nodes.
3. Created Kubernetes Deployment File using Docker image and Deployed using `kubectl apply <PARAM>` commandline.
4. Exposed the application using `kubectl expose <PARAM>` cli.

**Latest Update From AWS EKS Service:**

AWS recently announced AWS EKS Worker node creation support using AWS SDK. So now Creating EKS environment can be done using SDK itself.

===================

**Update:**

Now AWS has Supported Creating worker node thorugh UI and AWS SDK.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EKS.html#createNodegroup-property

Comment: Did you install any packages on Jenkins agents to communicate Jenkins agent with EKS cluster?

Comment: installed "eksctl", Command line tool especially for EKS Service by AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Why not configuring `kubectl` for jenkins and deploy apps using `kubectl apply deployment.yaml` command?

Once you have kubectl config you can save it as secret text. I had an assignment for the interview and here is an example of such deployment:
https://github.com/mtuktarov/hello

It uses shared lib:
https://github.com/mtuktarov/hello-jenkins-lib

Comment: I want to deploy application on another machine, not in Jenkins installed machine. Can we deploy application to remote machine using kubectl?

Comment: yes, refer to the official documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/